# Error al iniciar una migracion con el comando ((add-migration CompleteDB )) en Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net

Al momento de iniciar una migración lo hago por consola con el comando:

```
add-migration CompleteDB
```

al iniciar el proceso tengo un error como el de la siguiente imagen

[image: Aqui supongo que en la clase contract me pide que agregue una PrimaryKey]

Pego el siguiente codigo de la clase donde me pide que agregue en PrimaryKey incluso agregandole un

```
[Key]
```

```
using MyLeasing.Web.Data.Entities;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyLeasimg.Web.Data.Entities
{
    public class Contract
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Is Active?")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDateLocal => StartDate.ToLocalTime();

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is mandatory.")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndDateLocal => EndDate.ToLocalTime();

        public Owner Owner { get; set; }

        public Lessee Lessee { get; set; }

        public Property Property { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Has probado re-compilar la solución y luego ejecutar ese comando?

Comment: Saludos Fredyfx, ya pude resolver.

1) Tenía unos errores en la relación de las tablas

Comment: En ese caso, agrega la solución en la parte inferior de esta página, donde dice "Tu Respuesta" detallando lo que hiciste, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo problema o uno similar :D